# (JS) Generate list of all possible usernames with requirements

Tags: javascript

I own https://cobaltstats.com, which is a game tracker website. Currently, it caches all stats and refreshes them every so often. However, if someone looks someone else up and that user hasn't been looked up before, it takes a while to load. So I'd like to set up a program to loop through all possible users to cache their stats. How can I generate all possible usernames with these requirements:

- Usernames must start with a letter
- Usernames may contain the following punctuation: underscore (_), dash (-) and period (.)
- The length must be between 3 and 15 characters
- Usernames cannot start or end with letter combinations reserved by the company (i.e. ubi_ or _ubi).

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Are you saying that you wish to loop through over 10^20 usernames and lookup the stats for each one?  If you could do a billion lookups a second, this would still take you over a thousand years per loop.  Unless I misunderstand the situation.

Comment: @crosen9999 Sorry for the vagueness. I was trying to only find them with known names or words in them. While I understand that this would take a while, I think doing it would be a helpful start in speeding up the website. I also only want to do it once.

Comment: Begin caching names now the first time they are looked up.  Don't waste time and effort caching a giant list of what is mostly not actual names.

Comment: @GirkovArpa That's what I'm doing now. I can also check if a name is valid or not, and I would only add it to the list if it was.

Comment: I see.  Well based on @crosen9999's calculation ... good luck if you decide to pursue this anyway :P